# Does TCP still send new packet after packet loss is detected

Tags: tcp, packet-loss

Let's say TCP already detected packet loss and re-transmitted packet, does it continue to send new packet before the acks of re-transmitted packet arrives.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, if retransmission is triggered, tcp will enter congestion control mode, the congestion window will be reset to 1 MSS, so it can continue  to send at most 1 MSS size of data without ack.

Comment: i don't think this is how it work now. It worked like this maybe 30 years ago.

Comment: you would want to read into loss recovery phase in "reno", then "new reno", then "tcp sack", and "proportional rate reduction". there was something in between, but i don't remember how it is called.